# How can I show admob ads in certificated app by phonegap builder?

Tags: android, admob, keystore, phonegap

I have developed app via HTML5, JS, CSS, PHP and MySQL by help of phonegap builder. I have used admob plugin successfully in my app, but when I add keystore to my app on phonegap builder, there were no ads in my certificated app. Below is my config.xml plugin code

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec ="~2.35.3" source="npm" >
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.0.0" />
</plugin>
```

Below is JS codes. Everything is ok when I open apk without keystore.

```
var admobid = {};
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-3620418953743637/6097985822',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-3620418953743637/2453242527',
        rewardvideo: 'ca-app-pub-3620418953743637/6437036798'
    };
} 



function initApp() {
var oyunSonu = localStorage.getItem("oyunSonu");
$('#reklamKont').fadeIn();

if(oyunSonu != "1"){
      $('#reklamKont').fadeOut();
}

AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId: admobid.interstitial,
    autoShow: false
});

        AdMob.prepareRewardVideoAd({
        adId:admobid.rewardvideo,
        autoShow: false,
      });


}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


function odulReklamFNC(){

if(odulTusAktif == 1)
{
    AdMob.showRewardVideoAd();
    odulTusAktif = 0;


}
}


var odulTusAktif;
document.addEventListener('onAdLoaded',function(data){ 

if(data.adType == 'interstitial'){
    var oyunSonu = localStorage.getItem("oyunSonu");
    if(oyunSonu == "1"){
        localStorage.setItem('oyunSonu', '0');
        $('#reklamKont').fadeOut();
        AdMob.showInterstitial();
        }
}

 if(data.adType == 'rewardvideo'){
        odulTusAktif = 1;
        if(odulBTNGoster == 1){
        $('#odulBTN').fadeIn();
        }



        }

//
});


document.addEventListener('onAdPresent', function(data){ 

        if(data.adType == 'rewardvideo'){


            var uyeCookie = localStorage.getItem("uyeID"); 

            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: websitePHP + "odulVer.php",
            data: {
                id : uyeCookie

                },
                beforeSend: function(){ 

            $("#phpKont").fadeIn();
            },
            success: function(gelenVeri){ 
            $("#phpKont").fadeOut();
            $('#odulBilgi').html(gelenVeri);
            $("#gunlukPrim").fadeOut();
            $("#odulBildiri").fadeIn();
            document.getElementById('satinAlSES').currentTime = 0;
            document.getElementById('satinAlSES').play();
            odulBTNGoster = 0;
            girisAnaFNC();
            top10FNC();


        }

    })


        //$('#rumuz').html(data.rewardType);
        //$('#elmas').html(data.rewardAmount);
        }

});



document.addEventListener('onAdFailLoaded',function(data){ 
        if(data.adType == 'interstitial'){
        localStorage.setItem('oyunSonu', '0');
        $('#reklamKont').fadeOut();
        }

        if(data.adType == 'rewardvideo'){

        }

    });

    document.addEventListener('onAdDismiss',function(data){ 


        if(data.adType == 'rewardvideo'){
            if(odulBTNGoster != 0){
            window.open('baslangic.html','_self');

            }

        }

    });
```

How can I fixed this problem. I have also worried about that it will happen when I upload my app to google play services.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Are there any errors that are being logged that you could provide so that other users on Stackoverflow can help you out? If there are no errors, it would be great to include that as a piece of information to help rule out some of the first things people will look for.

Comment: I can build my app and then add keystore and rebuild my app without error. There were no errors. I can setup android app on my mobile phone and run it. Everything is working fine except admob.

Comment: Yes, that does not tell you if there are errors occurring at runtime that are preventing the ads from showing up. Not sure if phonegap works nicely with the Logcat utility that Android provides but knowing whether there are errors occurring at runtime or not would be a good place to start. See logcat doc https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: Isn't logcat usable on debuggable mode? When I add keystore by phonegap builder, debuggable mode is deactivated. How can I get log about errors?

Comment: When wait some time, it will show ads on my app. There is no need to any adjustment.